# Load and store contents of a webpage on local host with PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, curl

I need to read and store contents of a page, stored on my local PC, with PHP or JavaScript .
I am running a loaclhost on my PC at the following address and it has contents that I like to load the page and store the contents:

http://10.0.0.210:10009

obviously, I cannot use CURL or file_get_contents() from PHP as they pertain to the server side.
I could do a Location : url and open the local page, but I need to get the content and store it in a variable, so I can parse them.
What is the best way to achieve this? Javascript, jQuery. How? Thank you

Comment: Your computer is the server. No reason you can't access files on it using php. Don't confuse the public facing access for client requests with what you can do in the back end. Should be able to get what you need using file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

Try out JS APIs like localStorage, indexDB, sessionStorage for data. If you want to cache files, try out Application Cache.

Comment: AppCache is history https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Answer (score 0):

I think both CURL and jQuery (ajax) could do this. CURL is not server side only.